# Calling variable from another class in “python”

Tags: python, python-3.x

---

Good day Sir,
I have a problem in calling the variable date, group from class JB() and KL() because I want to compare if the group in JB and KL is 1 and the date for JB()==KL(), I want to print the date. I have tried some solution from this forum, but it seems like I have failed.

```
class JB(object):
    def __init__(self, date, timeslot, group):
        self.date = date
        self.timeslot = timeslot
        self.group = group

    def timetableJB(self):
        print(self.date)

tt1 = JB("8 Sept", (TS3_JB, TS4_JB, TS5_JB, TS6_JB), G1)
tt2 = JB("15 Sept", (TS3_JB, TS4_JB, TS5_JB, TS6_JB), G2)
tt3 = JB("22 Sept", (TS3_JB, TS4_JB, TS5_JB, TS6_JB), G3)

class KL(object):
    def __init__(self, date, timeslot, group):
        self.date = date
        self.timeslot = timeslot
        self.group = group

    def timetableKL(self):
        print(self.date, self.timeslot, self.group)

tt2 = KL("15 Sept", (TS1_KL, TS2_KL, TS3_KL), G1)
tt3_1 = KL("22 Sept", (TS1_KL, TS2_KL, TS3_KL), G2)
tt3_2 = KL("23 Sept", (TS4_KL, TS5_KL, TS6_KL), G3)

class PP(object):
    def __init__(self, date, timeslot, group):
        self.date = date
        self.timeslot = timeslot
        self.group = group

    def timetablePP(self):
        print(self.date, self.timeslot, self.group)

  tt3 = PP("22 Sept", (TS1_PP, TS2_PP, TS3_PP), G1)
  tt4_1 = PP("29 Sept", (TS1_PP, TS2_PP, TS3_PP), G2)
  tt4_2 = PP("30 Sept", (TS4_PP, TS5_PP, TS6_PP), G3)

print("")
print("Clash analysis for timetable KL and JB")

clashJB = JB()<----- I have error in this part
clashKL = KL()<----- I have error in this part
while clashJB.group and clashKL.group == G1:
    if clashJB.date == clashKL.date:
        print(clashJB.date)
```

Comment: Both of your classes need arguments to initilize an instance, but you're not passing any.  What do you expect `JB().date` to be, for example?  You aren't passing a value or defining a default value.

Comment: You are getting an error because your classes `JB` and KL` expect additional inputs when you initialize the class (i.e. date, timeslot, and group), but you are trying to initialize the classes without providing that information, which will throw a `TypeError`.

Comment: I have initialized the code with the input and I have updated the initialize part, but I have an error when I try to compare the date and the group

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting error because you are trying to create instances clashJB and clashKL without passing mandatory parameters date, timeslot, group . You need to create it as:

```
clashJB = JB(<date>, <timeslot>, <group>)
clashKL = KL(<date>, <timeslot>, <group>)
```

before you perform comparison operations.

You can go through https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html if you have any doubts related to class definition and its use.

Answer (score 0):

Following code work as per your expectation .

```
class JB(object):
    def __init__(self, date, timeslot, group):
        self.date = date
        self.timeslot = timeslot
        self.group = group

    def timetableJB(self):
        print(self.date)

class KL(object):
    def __init__(self, date, timeslot, group):
        self.date = date
        self.timeslot = timeslot
        self.group = group

    def timetableKL(self):`enter code here`
        print(self.date, self.timeslot, self.group)

class PP(object):
    def __init__(self, date, timeslot, group):
        self.date = date
        self.timeslot = timeslot
        self.group = group

    def timetablePP(self):
        print(self.date, self.timeslot, self.group)

clashJB = JB(1,2,'G1')<---- Note the change
clashKL = KL(1,2,'G1')<-----Note the change


while clashJB.group and clashKL.group == 'G1':
    if clashJB.date == clashKL.date:
        print(clashJB.date)
```